# How can I change array key value with php?

Tags: php, arrays, key-value

For example;

```
$array[16] = 20;
$array[18] = 8;
$array[27] = 95;
```

How can I change array[] key value start 0 like this;

```
$array[0] = 20;
$array[1] = 8;
$array[2] = 95;
```

I don't know key value. They can be change.  $array[16] can be $array[21]

Comment: You're not trying to change the *order* of the array, right?  Just reset the first key to zero and increment from there?

Comment: Looping over them will do the trick. But what is the need for resetting the keys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just assign the values to a new array with the same name:

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `array_values`

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

Comment: I agree, this is the most efficient for PHP imho.

Answer (score 1):

just use [array_values](http://www.php.net/array_values) like this
`array_values($your_array)` and you will have an array starting from index zero.